# Cortex M3 - Systick NVIC Disable - Energy Saving FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos, cortex-m

I use FreeRTOS on a EFM32GG380F1024. The Cortex M SysTick is used for the RTOS tick, the low energy rtc (BURTC) is used during sleep to generate timed wakeup calls. Energy Mode is EM3 (Just Ultra-Low-Frequency still operating).

As soon as Freertos calls me with the "suppressTicksAndSleep" callback, i do as follows:

1. Enter Critical Section (Globally disable IRQs) with the call "__disable_irq()"
2. I disable (AT LEAST I TRY; WONT WORK CURRENTLY) the Systick Interrupt with the call to the register "SysTick->CTRL  = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;"
3. I setup and start the LowEnergy RTC (BURTC)
4. Entering EM3

The problem is, that just after the energy mode entrance, the SysTick interrupt kicks in an wakes the device:

This should not be possible for the reason:

1. the Energy Mode 3 disables HF and LF clocks, so the Systick counter should not even increment

Can someone help out? Why is this not suspending the Systick correctly?

Have a look at the screenshot of my tracealyzer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6CUO.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that systick is actually disabled? Specifically not just that you don't configure it personally (which I'm sure you don't) but that nobody else doesn't configure it (such as `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt` function in FreeRTOS). Check NVIC registers values.

Comment: good idea. yes currently FreeRTOS does this for me with its weak implementation of "vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()". I try overloading it and do it myself. feedback in 5 minutes :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be doing it. I'd recommend reading https://www.freertos.org/low-power-tickless-rtos.html. While I've never used FreeRTOS in tickless mode, to me it does seem like when not sleeping, the systick may have to be running - hence `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt` configuring it. `portSUPPRESS_TICKS_AND_SLEEP` should however disable it when no application task is running (see code attached in the link). "Tickless" isn't really "full tickless".

Comment: Yes i took this as goto-advice. the point is, the code example there is basically what im doing, "prvStopTickInterruptTimer" is in my case "NVIC_DisableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn)" but this wont work.. thanks

Comment: Personally I'd try to narrow down where the problem is, e.g. turn off Rtos and try to enable/disable Systick from your own main loop (e.g. under an `if` with a variable you manually change from debugger) - see if it behaves as expected. If it does, see where in `portSUPPRESS_TICKS_AND_SLEEP` do the interrupts get re-enabled and check if it gets called. See if timer configuration gets called again etc.

Comment: OK Feedback: you should not do it if you not choose to do a FULL tickless kernel implementation yourself. Freertos does not just setup the systick timer but also sets up some static variables in the port. For me: Nogo. I would like to go with the port of Freertos.

Comment: feedback 2: https://community.nxp.com/thread/418362. the nvic for cm3 is only working with target irqs, not with cortex m irqs since the IRQn MUST BE >=0.

Answer (score 5):

```
SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk
```

You are *not* clearing any bits in `CTRL`. That line should probably be like

```
SysTick->CTRL &= ~(SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk)
```

to clear all bits for `CLKSOURCE` and `ENABLE`.

Comment: the question is whether you wanna overwrite other bits or leave them be. but anyhow. i tried any possible way, not working. either its not stopping the systick or it stops it successfully but then the reenable wont work anymore. continue...

Comment: ... what makes me wonder is, is 99% of people using the systick as a always ON member? since there is no common library for this timer (There is no API for cortex m systick to disable interrupt, enable interrupt, reset counter value,.. as any driver does it with mcu specific hardware timers (EFM32, STM32,...)) or is everyone ignoring the systick and rather using a specific hardware timers on their MCU (so systick is most of the time not used at all??) ?

Comment: I think 99% of people don't care much about power saving and hence have no need to stop the systick.